# Google APIs Console: Error Creating OAuth 2.0 Client ID

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-oauth, google-api-console

I am trying to use the Google APIs Console to create an OAuth 2.0 Client ID as a Service Account.  This ID will be used to query my Google Analytics data through the Analytics API.  However, when I attempt to create the Client ID, the APIs Console displays the message, "An error has occurred.  Please retry later."  I have tried several times throughout the last two weeks, but I keep getting the same error message.  Can anyone advise me on what I'm doing wrong?  Or is there another way that I can access my Analytics data via the API without an OAuth Client ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue.  Apparently, the Google APIs Console does not allow a collaborator account to create new OAuth Service Accounts, only the owner account can do so.